# Is there a known mathematical term for the set of integer coordinates inside an $n$-dimensional cube?

Tags: reference-request

For example, for a $4$-dimensional cube of size length $10$ this set would be $\{(x,y,z,t)|0 \leq x,y,z,t \leq 10 \land x,y,z,t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

I am interested in this structure but all online references I can find use terms like "$n$-cube" to mean just the vertices, or the surface of this cube, but I am interested in the set containing its interior points, too.

Comment: What properties are you interested in? That should narrow it down if this set has a special name.

Comment: The set of integer points inside an $n$-dimensional cube of side length $x$ (an explicit example is given in the question body)

Answer (score 3):

Generally I see the term "lattice points" used for integer coefficients,  here is an example where they talk about how many lattice points are in a lattice cube (Three dimensional cube where all the vertices are lattice points)

[lattice cube](https://projecteuler.net/problem=579)

Note: the term "lattice" is one of the more overloaded terms in math/physics/chemistry.   This is just one of many of them.